# CSS :- Dynamically compute header's height and then place elements below it

Tags: css

I want to keep my header fixed in place like this:
[image]

And then I want to add the body content below the header:

```
<div>
      <Header />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div style={{ color: 'red', zIndex: 101 }}>Hello World</div>
    </div>
```

However in order to keep this responsive, I can't just go with some manual calculation like `marginTop: '10rem'` as based on different screen sizes it may vary. I want to know what's the best way around to deal with this?

Here's how I have styled my header:

```
.Header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: $light-bg;
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 10px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  animation-duration: $background-animation-duration;
  animation-name: animateFadeEffectLight;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  &_dark {
    background: $toggle-switch-color-dark;
    animation-duration: $background-animation-duration;
    animation-name: animateFadeEffectDark;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
}
```

[image]

Here's how my layout looks like:

```
 <div>
      <Header />

      <div style={{ color: 'red', zIndex: 101 }}>Hello World</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i think you should give your header a fixed height. This height should be a css variables, which you could then also use on other elements to give them for instance `min-height: calc(100vh - var(--topbar-height))`. If you need this to be responsive, if the topbar needs to change height, you can listen to window resize with JS, read the current height of the topbar and update the css variable. All other elements should "move" accordingly...

Comment: `<Header />` is not valid HTML. It must have an explicit closing tag. Also even though that is valid, it's not considered good practice to use uppercase letters in tag names.

Comment: @connexo actually its a JSX not HTML syntax. We use it in React to create Reusable components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `position:fixed;` you can use `position:sticky;` to the header element. So it is positioned based on the user's scroll position.

**Note:** A sticky element toggles between *relative* and *fixed*, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place *(like position:fixed)*.

```
.Header {
  ...
  position: sticky; // Instead of fixed
}
```

If you add this style property, on page loads the header will be `position:relative;` after page scroll happens it will change automatically to `position:sticky;` similarly fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the header with fixed height and content height takes all of the reset space:

e.g. header's height is 60px, and content's height could be set to:

```
calc(100vh - 60px);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/CSS/calc